# xmlhttprequest, 500 error in browser; works fine in soapui

Tags: javascript, browser, soap, soapui

I have a problem with a webservice i need to call to.

### Situation

I need to get information from a webservice, build by the company I work for. If i try to get the information via SOAPUI there isn't any problem and i get the information i need in the response. But after editing a script so i can get it via the browser i get a 500 error.

### Code

```
function soap() {
    try {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://**testserver**/test/services/smsproxy2.smsproxy2HttpsSoap11Endpoint', true);
        // build SOAP request
        var sr =
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sms="http://**service**/smsreport">' +
                '<soapenv:Header/>' +
                '<soapenv:Body>' +
                    '<sms:GetSMSReport>' +
                        '<sms:FromDate>2015-01-01</sms:FromDate>' +
                        '<sms:ToDate>2015-12-12</sms:ToDate>' +
                    '</sms:GetSMSReport>' +
                '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert('Working fine! See the console.');
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        var result = xmlhttp.send(sr);
    }
    catch (error) {
        alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
    }
}
soap();
```

### Explanation

This entire code is put in a html file. This code is between script tags in the html head tag.
The `**testserver**` and `**service**` parts are different in the real script.

### Problem

As soon as i open this (html)file in the browser, i get an 500 (internal Error) message in the console. The row which is specified with this message is the row on which the `xmlhttp.send(sr)` action is set.

### Effect

I can't get the information i need within the server. So i can't show anything on the webpage.

### Questions

Why do i get a 500 error in the browser and does this work without problems in SOAP UI? The URL which is called is exactly the same in the browser as it is in SOAP UI, so this shouldn't be possible.
How do i solve this?

### Tried

A lot of things, but nothing helped.

Comment: `500` means an internal server error. You need to look at the server (in the error logs) to find out what the error actually is.

Comment: What are you trying to do? soap request/rest/http request?

Comment: Quentin, The server doesn't put anything in the error logs.
Rao, I'm doing a soap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the connection easier (directly and not via a proxy), there was an error in the errorlog.

It said that the endpoint wasn't right, but this seemed okay. Also the XML seemed okay.

After trying some things i found the solution:

### Solution

The following row gives the error:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

I've deleted this row from my script and now it works fine.